# NLP - train a model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, natural-language, tf-idf

I have a large set of large texts (around 60K texts, each one having between 100 and 30K words). Each text has 5 corresponding values (the famous big5 traits). The task is the following: for a new unseen text, predict the following 5 values.

**My approach**:

1. Tokenize text with `word_tokenize`, stem each text with `PorterStemmer().stem`.
2. Run `TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=True, max_features=10000)` on the texts, then reduce the 10K dimension to 700 features with `PCA(n_components=700)`. So basically, now we have training data `X` (with size `60Kx1K` and y with size `60Kx5`).
3. Fit this data into a neural network with 2 hidden layers (256 and 128 neurons, respectively).
4. Predict

**Error metric**: a sample is classified correctly, if all of its 5 values are with no more than 10 difference than the original one.

- Expected model accuracy: 70%
- Current model accuracy: 36%

My question is: what methods could I use/what should I change in my current methods, in order to increase the accuracy? I am thinking that the fact that some of the texts have around 500-600 words maybe actually confuses the model because I have set it up to work on really large texts (because of the max_features and PCA).

A possible idea: Split each long text into subtexts of size `512` - for each subtext, label it with the original text labels. Then encode all the data using `BERT` - it accepts the maximum word length of `512`. Then we have augmented the data this way. The problem is - having so short texts may be not enough to capture the "big idea", that is, the 5 values perhaps can't be predicted by so short texts. The classification will be: split long texts into subtexts, classify each one, and average the classifications.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect the model accuracy to be 70%?

Comment: This is a requirement.

Comment: Update!!! I removed texts with less than 10K words and accuracy has jumped to 54% ! I need 16% more! :)

Comment: It sounds like you still have ideas to try. Do be careful to keep your evaluation consistent. A common mistake is to accidentally change the evaluation so that it is easier, rather than improving the model itself. For example, if you removed the short texts from the evaluation data as well, maybe the original model would have been better on only the long texts as well.

Answer (score 0):

The pretty much standard suggestions are:

- Remove stop words (either use a stop-word list) or do POS tagging and only keep nouns, adjectives, and verbs.
- If speed is not your primary concern, you can use something more complex than stemmer and lemmatize the text. Using [Spacy](http://spacy.io), it is almost one-liner including removing stop-words:

```py
[token.lemma_ for token in nlp(your_text) if not token.is_stop and not token.is_punct]
```

- Classical, old-fashioned ML still works quite well. Random forest on 10k features might work well too.
- You can use pre-trained word embeddings and mean-pool or max-pool them before providing them to the classifier. There is also an interesting work on getting sentence/text embeddings from word embeddings by [discrete cosine transform](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D19-1380.pdf).
- You can try [Doc2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) for representing the documents.
- Your idea about finetuning. BERT would certainly work well. You say your texts are 500-600 words long. If you think the relevant information is more towards the beginning of the text, you can cut off the first 512 tokens and to the classification on  that.